# Hot swapping in Spring Boot in Visual Studio Code

Tags: spring

I just started a Spring Boot project with Angular 4. And for Angular I can run `npm start` so that NPM compiles every change. But I can't figure out how to do that for Spring Boot. I can find some sources for Eclipse/IntelliJ but I would like to stay with my Visual Studio Code editor.

Answer (score 16):

A little late for this but I was searching for the same and got here.
Maybe this could be useful for someone else.

**The answer for that is in the documentation of spring.**

Read here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html

And then here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html

In case you have problems with the links...

**If your'e using Maven just add this dependency in your pom:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Or if you're using Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 11):

Open VSCode options (Ctrl+,) and search for 'hot code replace'. At Java Debugger, switch to 'auto'.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Gradle, you'll need to use:

```
dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.