# How do I enable hot reload in Java Spring Boot using VSCode?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to hot reload, meaning auto-restart the server on code change, in Java using Spring Boot and VSCode.

I expect the following steps to be enough:

1. Update `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

[This post says its enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144346/hot-swapping-in-spring-boot-in-visual-studio-code)

I run again using `mvn spring-boot:run` and expect updating code to restart it

My actual result is that it stays the same as prior to the code change

I also tried: [image]

Answer (score 0):

had the same doubt, you just need to get this extension.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRqGd.png)

if you dont want to open the url the name of the extension is spring boot dashboard